# Snort configuration dead end

Tags: configuration, rules, snort

I'm in a dead end at the configuration of snort.

In theory a simple problem.

I created a test rule to check if snort runs properly.

Location:\etc\snort\rules\local.rules

Content:

```
alert icmp any any -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ICMP on fire"; sid:10000001; rev:001;)
```

Then I ran on terminal :

```
 sudo snort -T -i enp0s3  -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Message I receive at the end of the initialization:

```
 "Snort successfully validated the configuration!"

 "Snort exiting"
```

But scrolling up I'm seeing:

```
Initializing rule chains...
0 Snort rules read
0 detection rules
0 decoder rules
0 preprocessor rules
0 Option Chains linked into 0 Chain Headers
```

No rules at all!

location is correct in conf file under

/etc/snort/snort.conf

```
 var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
```

Snort 2.9.17 Build 199
Ubuntu 20.04

Any ideas?Thnnks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend supplying the rule path when you execute Snort using the "--rule-path" flag.

Comment: Could you provide more details on what the terminal flag does?

Comment: It does what it says, specifies the path to the rules folder.

Answer (score 0):

The `--rule-path` flag is not available and not recognized.
As far I understand this variable is just that, a variable that's not used anywhere in the configuration file.
The only way/workaround that I found was include the rule files for ex.

In the snort.conf appending this.

```
.
.
.
.

include c:\local.rules
```

Besides that, someone found a way to match content in answer/response?
I mean, let suppose that I want to check if the server has answer with a known content, for ex: `success`. I've tried with bidirectional operator `<>` and `flow:to_client` but nothing has worked.